# Is there an opensource java library to interface to an image scanner?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, image-scanner

I would like to make a tool to capture images from an scanner, is there an opensource java library to control / interface with a scanner? (I found JTwain but is about EUR 3000)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I used mms-computing. Site is down at the moment but it's open source so you can still find the libraries on the net eg:  http://code.google.com/p/openbizcard/source/browse/trunk/integrated/Scanner/src/com/yov/lib/?r=103

It supports both TWAIN and SANE and works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Look here: http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/Java-Twain-image-acquisition

Comment: Thanks for the link Romain. Alas, no open source.